# How to separately control plot curve style and fill ColorFunction?

Tags: plotting, color

I'm plotting complex-valued functions using a common technique: plot the magnitude (modulus) on the vertical axis and fill the area below with color hues to indicate the phase (argument). Here is an example:

```
f[x_] := Exp[-x^2] Exp[10 I x];
Plot[Abs[f[x]], {x, -3, 3}, 
  Filling -> Axis, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[x, Hue[Arg[f[x]]/(2 Pi)]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  PlotPoints -> 500]
```

This works fine, but for aesthetic reasons I'd also like to add a black outline curve, like this:

[image]

I made this image by plotting the outline in a separate Plot, then combining the two plots using Show.  But that's pretty awkward, so I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it, preferably with a single Plot.  The problem seems to be that the ColorFunction setting controls both the curve and the filling underneath it.  Ideas?

Comment: (The PlotPoints setting isn't irrelevant here: a setting greater than the default is needed for color hues to show correctly.)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you can do this with the options to `Plot` but you can "fix" it afterwards:

```
Plot[Abs[f[x]], {x, -3, 3}, 
  Filling -> Axis, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[Arg[f[x]]/(2 Pi)]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False] /. 
  Line[pts_, _] :> {Thick, Black, Line[pts]}
```

[image: Filling with plot line]

(We are removing the `VertexColors -> Automatic` option from the plot line.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the options `MeshFunctions`, `Mesh` and `MeshShading`:

```
Plot[Abs[f[x]], {x, -3, 3}, Filling -> Axis, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[Arg[f[x]]/(2 Pi)]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 Mesh -> {{-3}}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, 
 MeshShading -> {Directive[Thick, Black], Directive[Thick, Black]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Notes:** We can not use `PlotStyle` because as stated in [Documentation >> Plot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot.html):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, (see [Documentation >> ColorFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorFunction.html)), we can use `MeshShading` since

[image: Mathematica graphics]